# Delphi GUI test application not working on Jenkins build server

Tags: delphi, jenkins, gui-testing, dunit

I'm busy implementing a Jenkins build server for Delphi 2007 projects, with DUnit for test applications. The previous solution was built in a very old version of Hudson, with extensive test code and a large scale of production applications. The build scripts are therefore established and I've managed to get the builds going.

However, I'm having some problems with the test applications. These normally work fine from a cmd line execution, which calls *TestApp.exe UseTestRunner:Text*. However, when running GUI tests, the windows do not popup and the test results are inconsistent.

I suspect it has something to do with the Jenkins service account permissions, but I'm not sure how to proceed. The service currently uses the logged in user account, for various permissions and access to the Delphi environment options that's required for builds. Thus the option to use the Local System account with access to the desktop is tricky and I'm not sure if that will fix the problem.

I'm new to the Jenkins environment and would appreciate any help!

Comment: Services usually run on a separate desktop. Check if there is some setting to run Jenkins service in interactive mode, so it has access to full desktop.

Comment: Try this:
1. Open Windows services (or run: services.msc)
2. Double click on Jenkins service
3. In Logon tab, check this box: "Allow service to interact with Desktop"
If this will not help, than run Jenkins slave as a regular windows app from a autorun.